# On unchecking Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, checkbox

On unchecking the Checkbox element should be removed from the array?

```
     {
           columns.columnNames && columns.columnNames.map(el => {  
             return (
                <div>
                   <input type="checkbox" value={el}  onChange={this.select_MS.bind(this)} /> {el}
                 </div>
                    )
               })
      }
```

**OnChange** event looks like  this

```
    select_MS(event) {

        var permissions = this.state.permissions;
        if (event.target.checked) {
            permissions.push(
                event.target.value

            )
        }


        this.setState({permissions: permissions});
```

After checking 3 elements the array looks like this:
     }[image]

After uncheck from the elements in the array it is still showing
[image]

Comment: You don't actually remove anything from your `permissions` before calling `setState({permissions})`

Comment: Where have you written code to splice array

Comment: if I'm not mistaken you have only managed the 'checked' case. You must also handle the 'unchecked' case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When unchecking, you are not removing it from the array..

```
select_MS(event) {
  var permissions = this.state.permissions;

  if (event.target.checked) {
    permissions.push(event.target.value);
  } else {
    permissions = permissions.filter(
      permission => permission !== event.target.value
    );
  }

  this.setState({ permissions: permissions });
}
```